# Can I use std::for_each to transform an arma::mat one column at a time?

Tags: c++, armadillo

I would like to perform a transformation column-wise on an Armadillo matrix, using std::for_each or a similar method from the algorithm header. The reason for this is that the actual transformation I will perform is heavy, and hence likely to benefit from parallelization. In addition, I need to process the matrix one column at a time when running this in parallel, since the transformation function depends on all the values in a given colum, but not the values in other columns.

Below is a workaround that does work, in this small example for a 4 x 3 matrix. Rather than using an `arma::mat` of dimension 4 x 3, I define a `std::vector` of size 3, whose elements are `arma::vec` of size 4. Hence I implicitly have a 4 x 3 matrix.

```cpp
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::vector<arma::vec> v{arma::randu(4), arma::randu(4), arma::randu(4)};

  for(auto x : v) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }
  
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](arma::vec& x){ x = arma::ones(4); });

  for(auto x : v) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

This does work, but as I'm using linear algebra functions in other places of my code, it would be more convenient to replace the following line:

```cpp
std::vector<arma::vec> v{arma::randu(4), arma::randu(4), arma::randu(4)};
```

with something like this

```cpp
arma::mat v{4, 3, arma::randu};
```

and then following by something like

```cpp
// does not work! Gives a double, and iterates over all elements.
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](arma::vec& x) {x = foo(); });
```

However, in this case I don't know how to define the iterator given to `std::for_each` so that it works one column at a time, and in addition gives an `arma::vec`. [The iterators described in the Armadillo documentation](https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#iterators_mat) seem to give me the start of a given column, but then iterate one element at a time.

I am also aware of the [`for_each` member functions provided in Armadillo](https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#for_each), which would work sequentially, but the goal here is to perform parallel processing by eventually using [the overload of `std::for_each` taking an execution policy as its first argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each).

Comment: Øystein, did you try my suggestion? If you have any questions, just let me know.

Comment: Sorry Ted, I haven't had the time to try it yet, but the answer looks excellent. Will try tonight and accept the answer when I'm able to make it work.

Comment: No worries. I'm just curious since I haven't really used `arma` myself.  :)

Comment: Tested it now, and it works perfectly. I can use C++23 for my application, so will go with the non-Boost option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of rows is available in `arma::mat.n_rows` and you get iterators to each row with `v.begin_row(row_index)` and `v.end_row(row_index)`.

If you want to use the parallel execution policy on the *outer* vector in `v`, you could do something like this (which just prints the values):

```cpp
#include <armadillo>
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>
//
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    arma::mat v{4, 3, arma::fill::randu};

    // create a pair of counting iterator to iterate through
    // the indices [0, v.n_rows) :
    boost::counting_iterator<std::size_t> beg(0);
    boost::counting_iterator<std::size_t> end(v.n_rows);

    // for_each with an execution policy on the outer part of v:
    std::for_each(std::execution::par, beg, end, [&](std::size_t idx) {
        std::for_each(v.begin_row(idx), v.end_row(idx),
                      [](auto&& colval) {
                          std::cout << colval << ' '; 
                      });
        std::cout << '\n';
    });
}
```

If you don't want to use boost, you can create your own counting iterator - or fill a `std::vector<std::size_t>` with the indices you'd like to iterate over. Filling that takes a little bit of time so if you need to do it often, use a counting iterator.

In C++23 you could also use the normal `begin()` and `end()` iterators of the `arma::mat` and chunk it up in `v.n_cols` sized sub-ranges using [`std::views::chunk`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/chunk_view):

```cpp
#include <armadillo>
//
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    arma::mat v{4, 3, arma::fill::randu};

    auto cv = std::views::chunk(v, v.n_cols);

    std::for_each(std::execution::par, cv.begin(), cv.end(),
                  [](auto&& subrange) {
                      for(auto colval : subrange) {
                          std::cout << colval << ' ';
                      }
                      std::cout << '\n';
                  });
}
```

---

If you instead want to use the parallel execution policies on the *inner* vector in `v` it's much simpler:

```cpp
for(std::size_t idx = 0; idx < v.n_rows; ++idx) {
    // execution policy on the inner part of v:
    std::for_each(std::execution::par, v.begin_row(idx), v.end_row(idx), ...);
}
```